# SSIS 2005 how to resolve the error "input column has lineage id that was not previously used in the data flow task" programmatically

Tags: validation, sql-server-2005, input, ssis

I'm trying to write a program that automatically add columns from the OLE DB Sources in all of the components in a .dtsx file (the target is SSIS 2005). When I process the .dtsx with my program seems that the columns are added correctly, but when I open the modified package, in the components appears this message:

> input column has lineage id that was not previously used in the data flow task.

If I double click on the component and then I press OK the error disappear.

**My question is:**

is there a way to have the same behavior programmatically? I'll try to automate this operation for the user by using this program but with this error block me in the project.

Comment: I am not sure how you are adding columns but it seems like the columns you are adding are getting added correctly but the metadata is not getting updated. When you open the component, the metadata gets updated and the error goes away. You should be asking how to update metadata programmaticaly. Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing how you are adding the columns and assigning their lineage id, it is impossible to diagnose this issue.

Comment: I would compare the package (it is XML) before and after opening component in designer, and see what changed. It might hint on what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem, i could resolve that by bellow solution but i know it's not useful solution.
meta data can not detect your changes , **you can delete your task and create again that task**.

Answer (score 0):

Lineage ID must be invalid,
Option 1 delete data flow and add again & remap all column
Option 2 Open the SSIS package XML Code and search for an invalid Lineage column, copy and paste existing lineage and it should work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiQfW.png)

Answer (score -2):

Both source and destination column must have the same linage id.

Comment: What a brilliant answer!